# How to print a bar code with Star Line Command ESC b n1 n2 n3 n4 d1...dk RS

Tags: java, printing, label, barcode

i need an example to print a bar code with this command in java. The bar code i need it's for a 10 numbers.

ESC b n1 n2 n3 n4 d1...dk RS

i have center, left and cut, but i need a bar code.

```
 char[] CENTER = new char[] {0x1B, 0x1D, 0x61, 1};
  char[] LEFT = new char[] {0x1B, 0x1D, 0x61, 0};
  char[] cutP = new char[]{0x1b, 0x64, 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code, for a   JAN/EAN 13 bar code

char[] barcodeBeg = new char[]{0x1b, 0x62, 3, 2, 3, 100,'1', '2', '3', '4',0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x33,0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33,0x1E};